# Find a formula for partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How to find a formula for:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n\,(n+2)\,(n+3)}\:\:\:?
$$

I have tried to decompose each term into partial fractions to get a telescoping sum, but similar terms are too scattered around for me to find a pattern:
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{6n} - \frac{1}{2n+4} + \frac{1}{3n+9}, \: n \geqslant1
$$
WolframAlpha gives the answer $\frac{5}{36}$ for the infinite sum which I am interested in, and yes, I know what telescopic cancellation is as mentioned above.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac 1{n(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac {N(5N^2+30N+37)}{36(N+1)(N+2)(N+3)}$$

Comment: You should include in your post the things you have tried, what techniques do you know, or where you're stuck in your process, or else you'll get downvoted and probably won't get a good answer

Comment: @alosc okay thanks

Comment: Why do you think such a formula exists ?

Comment: You have ill-typed your formula, it should be $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+2)(k+3)}$

Comment: @JeanMarie because WolframAlpha says so

Comment: $\frac1{2n+4}=\frac1{3n+6}+\frac1{6n+12}$. Then?

Comment: 1) What is the answer given by Wolfram Alpha ? 2) Do you know the technique called "telescopic cancellation" ? it could be a way to solve your problem.

Comment: @JeanMarie done.

Comment: I don't understand : the answer 5/36 is surely for $N=\infty$. But you want a closed-form formula for a finite $N$...

Comment: You have done most of the job, now just do a change of index to cancel most terms since $\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}=0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry, I'm a little bit tired rn, edited again

Comment: @Lelouch solved, I'll post the answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done most of the job. Just note that $(\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}) = 0$ (which is always the kind of equality required when we want to do telescoping after a partial fractions decomposition).

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+2)(k+3)} &= \frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+2} + \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k+3} \\
&= \frac{1}{6} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=3}^{n+2} \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=4}^{n+3} \frac{1}{k} \\
&= (\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}) \sum_{k=4}^n \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{6} ( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}) - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}) + \frac{1}{3} (  \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}) \\
&= \frac{1}{6} ( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}) - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2}) + \frac{1}{3} (  \frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3}) \\
\end{align}
Then it is only a matter of simplification.

As a sanity check we can notice that this expressions goes to $\frac{1}{6} ( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} ) = \frac{5}{36}$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n = \frac16\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n - \frac12\sum_{n=3}^{N+2}\frac1n + \frac13\sum_{4}^{N+3}\frac1n  \\=\frac{5}{36}
+\frac13\left(\frac1{N+1} + \frac1{N+2}+ \frac1{N+3}\right) - \frac12\left(\frac1{N+1} + \frac1{N+2}\right)
$$